How dynamically use services based on config from database?
My code looks like this:
class Message

textGenerator
imageGenerator
imageScanner
imageScannerV2

class TextGenerator
class ImageGenerator
class ImageScanner
class ImageScannerV2
My config in db has the following structure:
{
  textGenerator: TextGenerator,
  imageGenerator: ImageGenerator,
  imageScanner: ImageScannerV2
}

I have some class BaseMessage which has some fabric method resolveHandler and which, based on config from database is supposed to return an instance of relevant handler.
The question is, how do I implement something like this in NestJS without keeping some map in the context of BaseMessage where key would be stringified name of handler and its value is a regular class. I want to avoid it because this way I would need to inject literally more than 20 services this way and it looks wrong.
What I want to achieve is to be able to dynamically resolve the handler that further could be use for specific job. For example I need to resolve ImageScannerV2. All the image scanner handlers would have the same contract so I will be easily to pass required params to it and call it to do the job.
Please help with some examples, guides or anything that would be useful as I can google nothing about this.

Could you please provide more context? I do not understand what you want to achieve

@Moti What I want to achieve is to be able to dynamically resolve the handler that further could be use for specific job. For example I need to resolve ImageScannerV2. All the image scanner handlers would have the same contract so I will be easily to pass required params to it and call it to do the job.

If the config depends on the database and you need to take a class dynamically how would you like to achieve it in ideal world? I mean at some point you need to take the needed class based on config in the runtime, so this "20 services" need to be injected somewhere

If my understanding is correct you could also provide a class in the DI with useFactory, e.g. { provide: YourInterface, inject: [YourConfig], useFactory: (config: YourConfig) => { ... }}

To achieve dynamic resolution of handlers in NestJS without relying on a map in the context of BaseMessage, you can leverage NestJS's Dependency Injection (DI) system and custom providers.
Step 1: Define Interfaces for Handlers
Start by defining interfaces for your handlers to ensure they all have the same contract. For example:
interface TextGenerator {
  generateText(): string;
}

interface ImageGenerator {
  generateImage(): Buffer;
}

interface ImageScanner {
  scanImage(image: Buffer): boolean;
}

interface ImageScannerV2 {
  scanImageV2(image: Buffer): boolean;
}

Step 2: Implement Handler Classes
Implement classes that adhere to these interfaces. These classes will contain the actual logic for generating text, images, or scanning images.
Step 3: Configure Providers in Module
In your module, configure providers to map these interfaces to their corresponding handler classes:
// message.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseMessage } from './base-message';
import { TextGeneratorHandler, ImageGeneratorHandler, ImageScannerHandler, ImageScannerV2Handler } from './handlers';

@Module({
  providers: [
    BaseMessage,
    TextGeneratorHandler,
    ImageGeneratorHandler,
    ImageScannerHandler,
    ImageScannerV2Handler,
    { provide: 'TextGenerator', useClass: TextGeneratorHandler },
    { provide: 'ImageGenerator', useClass: ImageGeneratorHandler },
    { provide: 'ImageScanner', useClass: ImageScannerHandler },
    { provide: 'ImageScannerV2', useClass: ImageScannerV2Handler },
  ],
  exports: [BaseMessage], // Exporting the BaseMessage class to make it available in other modules
})
export class MessageModule {}

Step 4: Use @Inject() Decorator in BaseMessage
Inject the handlers into the BaseMessage class using the @Inject() decorator:
@Injectable()
export class BaseMessage {
  constructor(
    @Inject('TextGenerator') private readonly textGenerator: TextGenerator,
    @Inject('ImageGenerator') private readonly imageGenerator: ImageGenerator,
    @Inject('ImageScanner') private readonly imageScanner: ImageScanner,
    @Inject('ImageScannerV2') private readonly imageScannerV2: ImageScannerV2,
  ) {}

  resolveHandler(handlerName: string) {
    switch (handlerName) {
      case 'TextGenerator':
        return this.textGenerator;
      case 'ImageGenerator':
        return this.imageGenerator;
      case 'ImageScanner':
        return this.imageScanner;
      case 'ImageScannerV2':
        return this.imageScannerV2;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Handler '${handlerName}' not found`);
    }
  }
}

Finally you can now use the resolveHandler() method to dynamically resolve handlers based on their names. For example:
// another-module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageModule } from './message.module';
import { BaseMessage } from './base-message';

@Module({
  imports: [MessageModule], // Importing MessageModule to make BaseMessage available for injection
})
export class AnotherModule {
  constructor(private readonly baseMessage: BaseMessage) {}

  someMethod() {
    // Example usage of resolveHandler
    const textGeneratorHandler = this.baseMessage.resolveHandler('TextGenerator');
    const generatedText = textGeneratorHandler.generateText();
    console.log('Generated Text:', generatedText);
  }
}

